# ReactJS connection with database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, frontend, backend

I want to get the data from front end react js form and insert in to mysql database using backend express. Can you tell me the flow from front end to backend with simple one field form using react js and then insert into database.

Comment: I have make till now signup form in reactjs.

Comment: people will be hesitant to help until you show you've made an effort. Post some links to docs you've read. Show your attempt at coding this, then post your code and ask for help

Comment: That's make sense .. absolutely correct

Comment: I don't really understand what is it that you don't know. The way your question is phrased sounds like you don't know **anything** about web development, which might lead to a different answer to what you expect. Please specify what is it that you don't know, so that we can answer according

Answer (score 14):

Lets take an example of a simple library application having table(`books`) with fields `book_name` and `author` .

#### Lets see the Backend Code First(in Node Js)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(

        connection(mysql,{

            host: 'localhost', //'localhost',
            user: 'userEHX',
            password : 'hMmx56FN4GHpMXOl',
            port : 3306, //port mysql
            database:'sampledb'

        },'pool')); //or single

       app.post('/add_book',(req,res)=>{

        let {book_name,author,} = req.body;


        if(!book_name) return res.status(400).json('Book Name cant be blank');
        if(!author) return res.status(400).json('Author cant be blank');

        var data={book_name:book_name,
                  author:author};


         var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO books set ? ",data, 
        function(err, rows)
        {

          if (err){
            //If error
              res.status(400).json('Sorry!!Unable To Add'));
              console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );
             }
         else
          //If success
          res.status(200).json('Book Added Successfully!!')

        });


        });


         app.listen(3000, ()=> {
      console.log(`app is running on port 3000`);
});
```

#### Now Let's see the Front End code on React Js:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class AddBook extends React.Component {

constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            bookname:'',
            author:'',

        };

    }


updateInfo = (event) =>{
        let fieldName = event.target.name;
        let fieldValue = event.target.value;
        if(fieldName === 'bookname') {
            this.setState({bookname: fieldValue});
        }
        else if(fieldName === 'author'){
            this.setState({author:fieldValue});
        }
};


addBook=(e)=>{

 let {bookname,author}=this.state;
 fetch('localhost:3000/add_book', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        bookname:bookname,
        author:author,

      })
    }).then(response=>response.json()).then(data=>{
         window.alert(data)
         //Do anything else like Toast etc.
})

}

render(){

return(



<div className="add_book">

 <div>
    <label>Book Name</label>
    <input onChange={this.updateInfo} name="bookname" value{this.state.bookname}/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label >Author</label>
  <input onChange={this.updateInfo} name="author" value={this.state.author}/>
</div>

<button onClick={this.addBook}>Add</button>                                 

</div>

    )

}




 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that establishes a connection to mysql.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'dbuser',
password : 's3kreee7',
database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect()

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err

console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
})

connection.end()
```

[Helpful guide to integrate popular Node.js modules for DBs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```js
**On REACT**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

//import isLoggedIn from '../../helpers/is_logged_in';
class Login extends Component {


   constructor(props) {
    const history = createHistory();
      super(props);

     // this.islogin = this.islogin.bind(this);
      this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
      this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
      this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        email:'',
        password:'',
        redirectToReferrer: false

      };
    }
    signIn(){

      const history = createHistory()
      const location = history.location;
              console.log(location);


    //  alert(this.state.email);
      axios.post('http://192.168.1.35:3012/users', {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      })
      .then(function (response) {
       // console.log(response.data[0].id);
       // console.log(response.data.email);
        var das =  localStorage.setItem('sessionid', response.data[0].id);
        var das =  localStorage.setItem('myData', response.data[0].name);
       var da =  localStorage.getItem('myData');
      var myid =  sessionStorage.setItem('myid', response.data[0].id);
      //alert(da);
       //history.go('/dash');
       
      })

      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

       this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
    }


    handleEmailChange(e){
      this.setState({email:e.target.value})
    }
    handlePasswordChange(e){
      this.setState({password:e.target.value})
}

  render() {
    console.log('11111');
          const myid =  sessionStorage.getItem('myid');
      const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/dash" } };
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;

    if (redirectToReferrer || myid !=null) {
          console.log('22222');

      return <Redirect to={from} />;
    }

else{

    return (
            <form className="form-signin" history={this.props.history}>
                <h2 className="form-signin-heading"> Please sign in </h2>
                <label className="sr-only"> Email address
                </label>
}
<input type="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required />              
  <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="sr-only"> Password</label>

<input type="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />  

<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.signIn} type="button">Sign in</button>            
            </form> 
    );
  }
}
}
export default withRouter(Login); 



**On Express**


var express = require('express');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
 var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var cors = require('cors')
var router = express.Router();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'test',
  database : 'example'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
 // console.log('You are now connected...')
})

/* POST users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body.email);
      user_sql = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (req.body.name, req.body.password);

     console.log(user_sql)
  connection.query(user_sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err

console.log(rows)
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));

   // res.json(rows);
});

   
       
 
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please add an explaination to your code. Furthermore your code snippet does not work, so either make it work or remove the functionality to use the code as a code snippet.